# How to concat to IEnumerable IGrouping?

Tags: c#, concatenation, ienumerable, igrouping

I have two IEnumerable IGrouping in my C# program:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, FileItem>> number1
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, FileItem>> number2
```

Is it somehow possible to concat these two IEnumerable into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the `Concat` method:

```
var concatenated = number1.Concat(number2);
```

For more info about this method, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`Concat` should work:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, FileItem>> concatenated = number1.Concat(number2);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that;

```
var groupedNumbers = number1.Concat(number2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't merge groups, but only concat the enumeration, with keys duplicated. The following code illustrate the issue:

var mergedGroups = firstGroups
.Concat ( secondGroups );

var duplicateKeys = mergedGroups
.GroupBy(group => group.Key)
.Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
.Select(group => group.Key)
.ToList();